# Diablo II resolution hack error

Tags: 12.04

Hi I recently installed Diablo II and wanted to use the mod to allow higher resolutions. Installation went great and everything is setup but when I try to load it via the executable I get this error

```
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so:                                                      
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file:   
No such file or directory
fixme:msvcr90:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x1000a3e0) stub
```

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please give us some details about how did you install Diabllo (wine ? Playon Linux) and if you have already applied any patches/fixes that blizzard has released

Comment: I installed the game via wine and applied the standard patch that floats around with the game. Also I was told by the wine team to ignore the p11-kit error so I guess Im just looking at the msvcr90 error. Maybe I should install it via wine tricks?

Comment: You should uninstall it, install it again, apply the official bug fixes patch http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-ii-patch-information end then apply any unofficial patches

Comment: Thanks that worked guess the res hack only works for some updates 1.13b I believe to be exact. Now I can finally play outside of a 4:3 resolution :)

Comment: then this should be marked as fixed

Comment: @SalihEmin sorry I don't know how to mark it as fixed

Comment: @SalihEmin Could you re-post your commant as an answer? Seems like the OP will not come here anymore.

Comment: @EricCarvalho I posted my comment as an answer as you suggested :)

Answer (score 2):

You should uninstall it, install it again, apply the official bug fixes patch [us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-ii-patch-information](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-ii-patch-information) end then apply any unofficial patches